# Shortcut for a polynomial of the form $a_nx^n+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$

Tags: math-mode, macros, shortcut

I currently taking a course in Algebra, and I find myself typing the polynomial

```
$a_nx^n+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$
```

over and over again, and I was wondering if I could create a shortcut for such a polynomial form, such that I can control what coefficients and variables I want.

I know the polynomial package exists, but I cannot seem to incorporate the "ldots" in the commands it offers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please tell us more about the "canonical form" of the polynomials you find yourself writing repeatedly. E.g., is the highest order always `n` (w/ `n>1`, right?) and is the lowest order always `0` , i.e., a constant?

Comment: Exactly as you say! and thank you for the warm welcome :) @Mico

Comment: Of course, the correct form for a polynomial is $(\cdots(a_nx+a_{n-1})x+\cdots+a_1)x+a_0$ ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that what you need is a macro that takes two arguments: the "name" of the coefficients, and the "name" of the base of the power terms. The names will, in general, be single letters, right? (You've indicated, in a comment, that the highest and lowest order of the polynomial are always `n` and `0`, respectively.) The macro called `\pn` in the following example satisfies these criteria.

Incidentally, the typographic ellipsis used between binary operators (such as `+`) is usually of the form `\cdots`, not `\ldots`. (The letters "c" and "l" refer to either *centered* (on the math line) or *low* (on the typographic baseline).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% The following macro must be used only in math mode:
\newcommand\pn[2]{#1_n #2^n + \cdots + #1_1 #2 + #1_0}

\begin{document}
$\pn{a}{x}$

$\pn{\lambda}{z}$

$\pn{\alpha}{\xi}$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up request: Suppose that not all polynomials are of order `n`, but that it's true that most polynomials are, in fact, order `n`. In that case, it makes sense to modify the `\pn` macro that it takes 3 rather than 2 arguments, with additional argument taking on the value `n` by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% The following macro must be used only in math mode:
\newcommand\pn[3][n]{#2_{#1} #3^{#1} + \cdots + #2_1 #3 + #2_0}

\begin{document}
$\pn{a}{x}$ % use default order (n) of polynomial

$\pn[4]{\lambda}{z}$

$\pn[q]{\alpha}{\xi}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is great :) (I would upvote, but I need 15 rep pts haha, as soon as I get them I'll take care of it!

Comment: Question, if I want to change the variable "n", how should I proceed? I am sorry to bother you again

Comment: @Kam - Please see the addendum I just posted. In this addendum, I changed the structure of the `\pn` macro so that it takes, in addition to the usual two mandatory arguments, an optional argument (to denote the highest order of the polynomial) whose default value is `n`.

Comment: +1 for generating enthusiasm :)

Comment: Re the dots, just `\usepackage{amsmath}` and use `\dots`, which will automatically put the dots at the correct level for the adjacent operators.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Thanks for this. Indeed, the `amsmath` package provides this nifty way of overloading, so that it resolves to either `\ldots` or `\cdots` depending on what precedes and follows `\dots`. However, not knowing how familiar the OP is with the `amsmath` package and its implementation of the `\dots` package, I thought it was wiser not to go that route. Instead, I chose to be explicit about which type of typographic ellipsis should be used in the present context.

Answer (score 12):

With a fairly simple syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\poly}{O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { poly } { #1 }
  \kam_poly:
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { poly }
 {
  degree  .tl_set:N   = \l__poly_degree_tl,
  var     .tl_set:N   = \l__poly_var_tl,
  coef    .tl_set:N   = \l__poly_coef_tl,
  reverse .bool_set:N = \l__poly_reverse_bool,
  degree  .initial:n  = n,
  var     .initial:n  = x,
  coef    .initial:n  = a,
  reverse .default:n  = true,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kam_poly:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l__poly_reverse_bool
   {
    \l__poly_coef_tl \sb { 0 } +
    \l__poly_coef_tl \sb { 1 } \l__poly_var_tl +
    \dots +
    \l__poly_coef_tl \sb { \l__poly_degree_tl }
    \l__poly_var_tl \sp { \l__poly_degree_tl }
   }
   {
    \l__poly_coef_tl \sb { \l__poly_degree_tl }
    \l__poly_var_tl \sp { \l__poly_degree_tl } +
    \dots +
    \l__poly_coef_tl \sb { 1 } \l__poly_var_tl +
    \l__poly_coef_tl \sb { 0 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\poly$

$\poly[var=z]$

$\poly[var=t,degree=m,coef=b]$

$\poly[var=t,degree=m,coef=b,reverse]$

\end{document}
```

The keys can be specified in any order, freeing you from the need to remember which parameter goes first; the default values are

```
var = x
degree = n
coef = a
```

You can also make shorthands with, say

```
\newcommand{\polybtn}{\poly[var=t,coef=b,degree=n]}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for "fairly simple syntax". :-)

Comment: @Mico Fairly simple *user* syntax.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my post! I will definitely look into this as well :) where might you suggest I start properly learning about writing in Latex? I'm bewildered by what it seems to offer!

Answer (score 1):

I would propose `\poly{ax^n}`

```
\newcommand\poly[1]{\dopoly#1^n^\relax}
\def\dopoly#1#2^#3^#4\relax{#1_{#3}#2^{#3} + \dots + #1_{1}#2 + #1_{0}}
```

You can use `\poly{ax}` or `\poly{ax^n}`.